# How can I get Actual Route path From Route file in controller using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

How can I get Actual Route path From Route file in controller using Laravel 5.4

When i m using `$url =$request->route()->getPath();`  that occurs error message in laravel 5.4

message like that:

> - local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getPath() in E:\xampp\htdocs\newneptune\app\Http\Middleware\rollwise.php:25
>     Stack trace:

Comment: Does `$url = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();` work?

Comment: No, its not Working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$request->route()->getPath()` use  `$request->route()->uri()`

Comment: Its Solved Thanks @krishna

Answer (score 1):

Use `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getUri()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getUri() in E:\xampp\htdocs\newneptune\app\Http\Middleware\rollwise.php:26
Stack trace:`
occurs Error

Comment: You used `Route::getUri()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getPathInfo()`:

```
$request->getPathInfo();
```

It will return URI without GET parameters if any.

Comment: Its Comes look like that "/admin/clients/edit/35" but i want it like this "admin/clients/edit/{id}" base on define in route file..

Comment: @punit: you might want to add that info to your question, so other users can quickly see it

Comment: @punit the data you need is it the closure. You can get it with `$request->getRouteResolver()` (see use > route > uri), but I'm not sure if it's possible to get it from the closure.

Comment: @punit `request()->getRouteResolver()` works for me in 5.2, but it returns a closure that has data you're looking for.